# Flask building urls for api and view

Tags: python, angularjs, nginx, flask

I am writing a flask application with angularjs frontend. Templates aren't rendered from flask yet, they are delivered as static files. My api endpoint is as following:

```
@route('/projects', method=['GET'])
def rest_projects(self):
    """TODO: CRUD operation
    """
    Project = Model.get('project.project')

    return jsonify([project.serialize() for project in Project.search([])])
```

`url_for` works perfect with above endpoint but is there any way it can build urls for js templates also?. Say if url has api prefixed ie: `/api/tasks`, it comes to this handler otherwise deliver template.  Right now I am using nginx to achieve that but is there anything wrong in my design which is restricting me to do this from flask only.

Answer (score 1):

Flask is not intended to serve static files and you are better off keeping your files served by nginx for performance reasons.  You can serve static files however using `send_static_file()` or `send_from_directory` methods.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/